# How to render content_for with a block in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, templates

I haven't been able to find a solution elsewhere. This is the code I'd like to work:

```
<%= render :layout => "l/run" do %><%-
     content_for :error do
   -%>Error - Missing arguments<%-
     end -%>
<%=  render :inline => @api.data.views["html"], :locals => {:result => @result} %>
<%- end -%>
```

and in l/run:

```
<%-
...
  if readQuery.value?(nil)
-%><%= yield :error %><%-
  else
...
-%><%= yield %><%-
...
  end
-%>
```

I feel like this approach should work but am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this should work

view1.html.erb

```
<%= yield :error%>
```

view2.html.erb

```
<% content_for :error do %>
  #your code
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. No rails errors are being raised, `yield` works fine, the issue is that `yield :error` displays no content.

Comment: what is the end tag you have before the content_for block? try to get only the content_for tag in to one ruby code block (like in my example) and c how it goes, seems like your content_for tag is never called

Comment: You're right I think, however as I wrote in my post I've already tried that. I'll update my q with that code.